# Why do we need to use the recursive option to remove or copy folders

Tags: command-line

Why does Ubuntu, and any other unix system for that matter what you to use "remove recursively" for folders or copy recursively. I can only imagine it's a security thing but the name recursive doesn't imply such a thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is mostly for historical reasons. The following is a slightly modified extract from an excellent article named [A Brief History of the 'rm' and 'rmdir' commands](http://linuxgazette.net/issue49/fischer.html).

---

> A new version of `rm`, dated January 20, 1973, included these options:
>
> - `rm -f`: don't ask before removing read-only files
> - `rm -r`: recursively remove subdirectories
>
> The way the `rm -r` option was implemented at that time, when `rm` encountered a directory among the files it was removing, it would `cd` (then called `chdir`) to that directory and start another instance of `rm -r *` to remove its contents.
>
> A version which did the recursion within a single `rm` process appeared in the Seventh Edition of Unix in 1979.

---

More about the history of `rm` can be found by following the link above.